# Regarding "<", "<<", and reading files

Tags: cut

1. I know that I can do `tr a b < file`, but how do I do that for `ls`? So for example, How to feed `ls -l` a list of files from a 'file'. I tried the below and it did't work.

   ```
   $ cat>test
   A
   B
   C
   $ ls -l < test
   ```
2. I'm not clear on what "<<" or here document is used for.
3. One of my class exercises is to use vi to create a file with “:” on line 1 and “6/3” on line 2. Using line 1 as the delimiter and line 2 as the field, cut and display column2 from a file.

Am I supposed to loop and read the 2 lines into a variable? Do I use `sed -n '#p' (file)`? Is there an elegant 1 line solution?

Comment: You should have asked three different questions.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is:

```
ls -ld -- $(< file )
```

(assuming `ksh` or compatible shell)

but it has some issues, e.g. with whitespace or wildcard characters in filenames. So better use another approach:

```
xargs -rd '\n' ls -ld -- < file
```

(here assuming the GNU implementation of `xargs` for those `-r` and `-d` options).

Answer (score 1):

1. `ls` does not read from standard input, so input redirection does not do anything. What you want is command substitution.

   ```
   ls -l `cat list`
   ```

   or

   ```
   ls -l $(cat list)
   ```
2. Here documents are used to redirect standard input to fixed strings provided in the script instead of a separate file. You can also do it from the command line, but doing so has limited value and is not common.
3. This does not make sense.

Comment: So for #3 my current solution is:
LINE1: $delim=$(head -n1 viFile)
LINE2: $nameField=$(tail -n1 viFile | bc)
LINE3: $cut -d$delim -f$nameField someFile. Supposing there is a file with two columns delimited by ":".

Answer (score 0):

Answer part one:

1. you can use `while` loop to pass file content to 'ls' commnad.

   ```
   while read line ; do
   ls -l $line 
   done < file
   ```
2. dirty way to do it:

   ```
   counter=1
   while read line ; do
       if [ $counter -eq 1 ] ; then 
           delimiter=$line
           counter=$((counter+1))
       elif [ $counter -eq 2 ] ; then
           field=$line
           counter=$((counter+1))
       else
           echo File ended.
       fi
   done < inputfile
   ```